# ECS Task Definition - When overriding ENTRYPOINT, Docker image's CMD is dropped

Tags: amazon-ecs, aws-fargate

I have a Docker Image built with the following CMD

```
# Dockerfile
...
CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]
```

When my task definition does not include `entryPoint` or `command` the task successfully enters a running state.

```
{
  "containerDefinitions": [
    {
      "image": "<myregistry>/<image>",
      ...
    }
  ]
}
```

I need to run an agent in some instances of this container, so I am using an `entrypoint` for this task to run my agent.  The problem is when I add an `entryPoint` parameter to the task definition, the container starts and immediately stops.

This is what I'm doing to add the `entryPoint`:

```
{
  "containerDefinitions": [
    {
      "image": "<myregistry>/<image>",
      ...
      "entryPoint": [
        "custom-entry-point.sh"
      ],
    }
  ]
}
```

And here is the contents of `custom-entry-point.sh`:

```
#!/bin/bash
/myagent &
echo "CMD is: $@"
exec "$@"
```

To confirm my suspicion that CMD is dropped, the logs just show:

```
CMD is:
```

If I add the CMD array from the Dockerfile to the task definition with the `command` parameter, it works fine and the task starts:

```
{
  "containerDefinitions": [
    {
      "image": "<myregistry>/<image>",
      ...
      "entryPoint": [
        "custom-entry-point.sh"
      ],
      "command": [
        "nginx",
        "-g",
        "daemon off;"
    }
  ]
}
```

And the logs show the expected:

```
CMD is: nginx -g daemon off;
```

I have many docker images with various iterations of `CMD`, I do not want to have to copy these into my task definitions.  It seems that just adding *only* an `entryPoint` to a task definition should not override a docker image's `CMD` with an empty value.

Hoping some ECS / fargate experts can help shed some light on a path forward.

Comment: did you find answer for this?

Answer (score 2):

Some tips:

1. Check if your entrypoint script is executable
2. Use absolute path to your entrypoint script
3. Check logs to see the error. hopefully you autoconfigured awslog driver?
4. Have you successfully run the entrypoint version on your local?

Also have a read of this for some useful background:
https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/opensource/demystifying-entrypoint-cmd-docker/

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this has anything to do with ECS. This is how Docker behaves, and there's no way to change it as far as I know.

See https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/

> If CMD is defined from the base image, setting ENTRYPOINT will reset CMD to an empty value. In this scenario, CMD must be defined in the current image to have a value.

This particular snippet only refers to defining a new ENTRYPOINT in the image, but this Github [discussion](https://github.com/docker/docker.github.io/issues/6142) confirms the same behavior holds when overriding ENTRYPOINT at runtime.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same problem, with my entrypoint and command attributes being something like `sh -c ...`. I needed to delete `sh -c`, put the commands directly, and add `#!/bin/sh` at the top of my scripts.